# Dynamically filter data from one excel worksheet to display on another

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a straight forward way to have data stored in one worksheet automatically filtered and displayed on a different spreadsheet. I want to be able to update the data in one sheet and have the filtered view on the other worksheet update automatically.

Comment: What kind of filtering?  Can you give some examples (some made up data and filtering, doesn't have to be anything real)?

Comment: Please [Edit] your post & add the Criteria to Sort & Filter like single or multiple Criteria, better add some sample data.

Comment: **Continue,,** if you want to automate the method to Sort then Filter,,, VBA macro would be a good option,, are you comfortable with Macro?,, [Edit] post & add TAG `VBA`.

Answer (score 2):

Another method using a data table

Using same Sheet1 Data

[image: sheet1 data]

On Sheet3 select cell A5 and press Ctrl + T to create data table and select my table has headers and then OK.

Select cell A5 and A6 and drag across the required number of columns

and edit text to your column headings

[image: Sheet3 Headings]

In cell A6 add the following formula

```
=IF(Sheet1!A2="","",Sheet1!A2)
```

and drag A6 across required columns then down required rows

[image]

then use filters as required.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by straight forward but you can as shown in my example below use formulas to filter and return matching rows:

From data in my sheet1 I can filter for data with specific text in a column

[image: Sheet1]

on Sheet2 add headings and type the text you wish to filter for in  B1.

[image: Sheet2 headings]

In A5 add the following array formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$C$7,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7=$B$1,ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7)-ROW(Sheet1!$B$2)+1),ROWS(Sheet1!A$2:Sheet1!A2)),1), "")
```

Press Ctrl + Shift +Enter to enter the formula as an array you will see the formula will be encased in curly brackets {}

Drag the formula in A5 across B5 to C5 to populate the row for the number of data columns required.

Ammend the formulas to increment the index column number.

Remember to ensure you re-enter the formula as an array formula by pressing Ctrl + Shift + Enter.

B5 should now show index column number 2

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$C$7,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7=$B$1,ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7)-ROW(Sheet1!$B$2)+1),ROWS(Sheet1!B$2:Sheet1!B2)),2), "")}
```

and C5 with column index 3 as follows

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$C$7,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7=$B$1,ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7)-ROW(Sheet1!$B$2)+1),ROWS(Sheet1!C$2:Sheet1!C2)),3), "")}
```

Drag these formulas down for your expected maximum number of data rows

Type in Animal vegatable or Mineral in Sheet2 cell B1 and the table should auto filter.

[image: Sheet2 completed]

This has tested ok for Excel 2010

You can automate this further by adding a Data Validation List for cell B1.

Comment: This one is better than previous answer,, or you may combine both as Method 1 & 2,,, but you have missed one issue SORT then Filter !!